# Manually select OSM features for export

Tags: openstreetmap

I'm looking to export all the paths that comprise a long hiking trail in Japan. Unfortunately while some of the paths are named, many of them aren't and some are named inconsistently.

Is there a way to manually select OSM features for export, instead of downloading the area within a large bounding box?

Comment: Can you tell us the name or location of this hiking trail? These are typically mapped as a [route relation](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Relation:route). If that's the case for your trail then downloading the whole trail is rather easy.

Comment: It's the Osaka Diamond trail. The trouble is that it's one trail that weaves through a network of other trails.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like it is not mapped yet in OSM (see https://hiking.waymarkedtrails.org/#?map=10!34.9031!135.7838). Maybe you know a source that is compatible with OSM's license or you can record a GPX track while you are going for a hike along the trail?

Comment: I'll look into it! Thank you for the information!

Answer (score 2):

This is a way how you can easily download every kind of OpenStreetMap object - some steps, but quite simple.

1. Zoom in to OpenStreetMap. You must zoom in enought to be able to use the object selection tool (step 2)
2. Choose the object selection tool (on the right, see screenshot)
3. Click on the object you want to download: the orange circle that appears when you click (screenshot) shows the area covered from which all objects will be selected

[image]

4. On the left, see the results: every OSM-object inside the orange circle is listed: Choose the object you are interested in, click it

[image]

5. See the Tags for the object, in some cases it's name or other attributes

[image]

6. Got to https://overpass-turbo.eu/
7. Zoom to the area you are interested in
8. Click Wizard and insert the tag you found before, in this case: highway=footway and run the query

[image]

9. In blue, you now see the selected objects (all that have the tag you were looking for)
10. Click export and select a data type. All selected objects (the blue ones) will be included in your download.

Data format: If you want to use it in Google Earth, chosse KML, for use as GPS-navigation, choose GPX and import it to your app; for use in the web, in QGIS or other GIS software, use GeoJSON

[image]

Answer (score 1):

JOSM has a plugin called [way downloader](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JOSM/Plugins/WayDownloaderPlugin). it says that it's typical use is to follow the route of a road which is made up of a number of ways by downloading each way in turn without having to download all the surrounding data.