# Creating border at a particular distance from country border

Tags: qgis

I am new to GIS platform. I am using QGIS. I want to create lines inside map similar to border of country at a particular distance (say 100 KM). My data is in geographic coordinate system.

[image: This is my final goal]

Comment: Its Geographic.

Comment: See also here for an answer to a similar question with step-by-step workflow (steps 1 to 7 is preparing data only, you already have that): https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/383587/88814

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would prefer to save the layer as a new file by changing its CRS into a projected one  using `Right click > Export > Save Features As...`. Select a suitable one for your data region. Maybe one of UTMs.

[image]

Then use `Processing Toolbox > Vector geometry > Buffer` tool with negative distance value (-100000 m).

[image]

Comment: Thanks man, this is very helpful.

Answer (score 6):

Using a m-based CRS you may buffer geometries using negative values, thus "shrinking" them.

The CRS should be based on m (or miles or feet) and not degree since results otherwise wouldn't be equi-distant.