Extracting border from shapefile and then calculate distance to the border
I started with a states boundaries shapefile. I want to extract a part of state border and then calculate the distance of village centroids to the nearest point on this border. I have already calculated village centroids.
I tried extracting the border using polygon to lines and then explode to select the required border. After that, I merged the selected border and saved it as another layer. However, when I am trying to calculate distance of village centroid to this border using Join attributes by nearest, it is calculating distance from a particular point on border for all the centroids.I suppose the image below shows the reason why is it doing so as after merging to create border line we have only one feature.

How to deal with this in QGIS?

Hi Ak2020, welcome to GIS SE. A distance can only exist between two points. So not sure what you mean. Please revise your question by editing the initial post to add more information. A screenshot showing what you expect could help. See also the answer here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/383587/distance-between-gps-travel-route-and-country-border

Sorry, the image doesn't clarify anything, it confuses even more. Your questionis unclear and risks to be closed. Please avoid that unpleasant experience and try to show visually what you intend to do.

Hi, sorry for the confusion. Thanks for the above link, I was able to resolve the issue.
