# Exporting separately ground and the sea from QGIS as TIFF files

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, dem

I am very bad at QGIS, but I really need to have TIFF of the area on the picture, to export it later to Unreal Engine. The problem is the sea. Unreal takes it as a part of the ground. It doesn't recognize the water. How can I export height map of the ground separately from the sea?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Get a polygon layer of the water surface, for example from OpenStreetMaps (OSM). See here how to download: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/368774/88814. Another option is to use the [QuickOSM plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QuickOSM/). You can use the OpenStreetMap tags `natural=water` (red on the screenshot) and `natural=bay` (blue).

You will get many very small water features, so probably you want to keep only a few and delete all that are smaller than a certain area. When extracting from OSM, keep the polygon layer only, delete line- and point layers.

Screenshot: using QuickOSM to extract features tagged `natural=bay` from OSM:
[image]

2. Than use the tool `Clip raster by mask layer` from the `Menu Raster / Extraction` (alternative: SAGA tool  `Clip raster with polygon`).

Comment: i am sorry but how to get a polygon layer of the water surface?

Comment: See updated question

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! But maybe you know, why can I get this error when i try to clip raster with polygon?.. https://prnt.sc/wm0hzh

Comment: See the error messages in `Log messages panel` where you find more information. Always post error messages as text, not as screenshot. To avoid lengthy discussions here in comments, post this as a new question. Be aware of the focused Q&A format, see [tour]. Describe what you did (you may link tothis post) and where yor're stuck.

Comment: Could have to do with wrong CRS