# Building route on defined graph of roads with intermediate stops in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, routing, polyline-creation, graph

I have a layer with stops of public ground transportation routes. I also have a layer with a graph of roads where public transportation can go.  I need to build a route from the first to the last route stop within the public transportation road graph layer.

I've tried using the Shortest path tool, it works for me because it requires specifying a layer with roads. But there you can build a route only between two points, which must be specified manually, I need a tool that will take into account the intermediate points, and they can be loaded automatically, using, for example, a table.

I attach below how the attribute table with stops looks like.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked if the public transport routes do not exist ready made to download in OpenStreetMap?

Comment: Like e.g. (based on your coordinates) https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/2649554 and https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/2649555 and https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/2651182 See also here how to download: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/368774/88814

Comment: Babel, I already have public transportation route stops. I just need to connect all the stops (points) into the most efficient route (line) automatically. Since manually I can connect them myself, but it only works for a hundred stops, while I have a thousand of them, so I would like to automate the work.

Comment: Have you clicked on the links? There you see the points (stations) are connected by a line. You can download this. No need to recreate the same by yourself

Comment: Babel, yes, I have lines of those routes myself. The problem is that not all of these routes are effective. So I need to build new routes from the same stops, but on different roads.

Comment: Sound like travelling salesman problem then... See https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=qgis+travelling+salesman

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it!